# Ellipsis to limit text height & width with Ionic

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework

I was trying to limit my text width & height , I usesd text-overflow: ellipsis in my CSS file but I got this result :

[image: Result]

my CSS is :

```
.ellipsis{
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: 12em;
    height: 12em;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    border: 1px solid #000000; }
```

Comment: Here is a fiddle for you: https://jsfiddle.net/mvcp49km/2/

Comment: Thank you but I got this result : When I add the CSS I got a scroll bar but it's wrapping all my "list card" instead of just the <p> tag i.stack.imgur.com/XWERo.png

Comment: Why you don't provide a fiddle of all your content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thank you all , 
I found a simple solution : [Pure CSS read more toggle](https://codepen.io/Idered/pen/AeBgF)

HTML:

```
 <div>
  <input type="checkbox" class="read-more-state" id="post-1" />

  <p class="read-more-wrap">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. <span class="read-more-target">Libero fuga facilis vel consectetur quos sapiente deleniti eveniet dolores tempore eos deserunt officia quis ab? Excepturi vero tempore minus beatae voluptatem!</span></p>

  <label for="post-1" class="read-more-trigger"></label>
</div>
```

CSS :

```
.read-more-state {
  display: none;
}

.read-more-target {
  opacity: 0;
  max-height: 0;
  font-size: 0;
  transition: .25s ease;
}

.read-more-state:checked ~ .read-more-wrap .read-more-target {
  opacity: 1;
  font-size: inherit;
  max-height: 999em;
}

.read-more-state ~ .read-more-trigger:before {
  content: 'Show more';
}

.read-more-state:checked ~ .read-more-trigger:before {
  content: 'Show less';
}

.read-more-trigger {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 .5em;
  color: #666;
  font-size: .9em;
  line-height: 2;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-radius: .25em;
}

/* Other style */ 
body {
  padding: 2%;
}

p {
  padding: 2%;
  background: #fff9c6;
  color: #c7b27e;
  border: 1px solid #fce29f;
  border-radius: .25em;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Multi-line ellipsis for Chrome. You can specify the number of lines to be displayed using `-webkit-line-clamp`. Some more techniques [here](http://hackingui.com/front-end/a-pure-css-solution-for-multiline-text-truncation/)

```css
.ellipsis {
  width: 12em;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 5;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
}
```

```html
<p class="ellipsis">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Maecenas porttitor congue massa. Fusce posuere, magna sed pulvinar ultricies, purus lectus malesuada libero, sit amet commodo magna eros quis urna.
</p>
```

Comment: When I add the CSS I got a scroll bar but it's wrapping all my "list card" instead of just the <p> tag
http://i.stack.imgur.com/XWERo.png